# Contains in LINQ query and Check for Not null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq Query. In that I am using a list with contains to filter some records. The query needs to look for the values that is not null in any one of the list values (100 or 110 or 120).

**List values**

```
List splitted = {"100", "110", "120"}
```

**Query**

```
model = (from line in db.Bibs
         where line.TNo == "245" 
           && (line.NrmVal.StartsWith(Val) || line.NrmVal.Contains(" " + Val))
         select new MyModel
         {
          Author = (from a in db.Bibs 
          where a.BId == line.Bid
            &&  splitted.Contains(a.TNo) 
            &&  a.NrmVal != null 
          select a.NrmVal).FirstOrDefault()
         }).ToList();
```

Any help in providing the solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And what's not working?

Comment: Throwing timeout exception when i execute the query. I think I am not following proper way to do this check **(a.NrmVal != null)**.

Comment: We need more information.  Is this LINQ to SQL?  What are the components of db.Bibs?  Your null check and the id check don't appear to be necessary, but I feel like we're missing information here.

Comment: Code looks fine to me? `TimeoutException` seems more related to network latency rather than your LINQ query - maybe it's taking too long?

Comment: I am sorry. That was actually subquery. Now, I updated my question. Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Lambda equivalent

```
var query = db.Bibs.Where(x => x.TNo == "245");
query = query.Where(x => x.NrmVal.StartsWith(Val) || x.NrmVal.Contains(" " + Val));
query = query.Select(x => new {
            Author = db.Bibs.Where(a => a.BId == x.BId && a.NrmVal != null && splitted.Contains(a.TNo)).FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

If you still get the same problem then I would comment out each section until you find which section doesn't work. I optimized the `Author` query to check for `null` first before looking up the list.

Also, it makes the code a bit easier to manage and arguable more readable.