# Check if List is not null when using "contains" in LINQ query else select all records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a **Search** functionality in my application and it has 4 criterias basically **Location**, **Status**,**PropertyType** *[List of String]* and **PriceRange** *[Min and Max Price]* and below is the `model`

```
public class SearchFilters
{
     public SearchFilters()
     {
          MinPrice = "10000";
          MaxPrice = "8000000";
     }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
     public string[] CategoriesId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
     public string[] LocationID { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
     public string[] StatusID { get; set; }

     public string MinPrice { get; set; }
     public string MaxPrice { get; set; }
}
```

When data is received in `controller` List of Values Selected from `SelectList` will be stored in `CategoriesId`, `LocationID` and `StatusID`. Now Selecting values from each of List is optional, it can be single or multiple. So I need to filter Database and also if user does not select any item then this `List` will be `null` since it is an optional search criteria.

**For Example**

Values for status can be "Ongoing","Upcoming" and "Completed". So I used below `LINQ` to extract data.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(SearchFilters smodel)
{
     var query=db.tblProperties.Where(p => smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation)).Select(x=>x).ToList();
     //.....
     //.....

}
```

> Just added one property comparison to demonstrate

This returns records without any problem, but if this `smodel.StatusID` comes `null` i.e. User does not select any value then this query fails with an `exception`. So how to overcome this? Also how to fetch all the `records` when no value is selected? Went through **[`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248348/contains-in-linq-query-and-check-for-not-null)** but the solution there wasn't useful to overcome this problem? Basically how can I incorporate a query for search in these situation?

Comment: *This returns records without any problem, but if this smodel.StatusID comes null i.e. User does not select any value then this query fails with an exception.* so check if `smodel.StatusID` is null first.

Comment: I hope the table is small and will never grow. Pulling an entire table is not advised because it scales poorly and can cause issues with both bandwidth and performance as well as giving the false impression to the front end that filtering, pagination, and search is not needed.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Formatting? He is talking about checking if `StatusID` is null before trying to accessing its collection

Comment: @AlexanderDerck That comment was reply to a comment which was deleted.. and not for Matt's comment.. Matt has a valid point..

Comment: @TravisJ As of now table is very small but might grow up in future.. Could  you please recommend any suggestions to handle when the table grows up?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - Just plan on it being large, and make sure you never grab the entire table. If someone doesn't include a value for that status, then it seems to me their validation should have failed. It is hard to tell what the implication is there though, because I only have this small snippet to view :) Feel free to include any other details, or visit us in the c# chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to do the `null` check outside of the query

```
var initialQuery = db.tblProperties;
if(smodel.StatusID != null)
{
    initialQuery = initialQuery.Where(p => smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation));
}
var query = initialQuery.ToList();
```

Or as a helper method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConditionalWhere<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
    Func<bool> condition, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    if(condition())
        return collection.Where(predicate);
    return collection;
}
```

And then

```
var query = db.tblProperties.ConditionalWhere( 
    () => smodel.StatusID != null,
    p => smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation));
```

And you can chain them together

```
var query = db.tblProperties.ConditionalWhere( 
        () => smodel.StatusID != null,
        p => smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
    .ConditionalWhere( 
        () => someOtherCollection != null,
        p => someOtherCollection.Contains(p.PropertyLocation));
```

This will avoid running whatever the `condition` is multiple times for Linq-to-Objects and will allow you to use something that cannot be translated to SQL for EF or Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: Well I could have opted for this but then I have multiple options to filter and this approach would be inefficient, i.e. to check all the filters..

Comment: Definitely a good option if your `if` clause was expensive. One way this can trip you up however is if the types of `initialQuery` aren't the same such that the assignment in the `if` clause fails (I don't think it will here, but on some more complicated queries it might).

Comment: @GuruprasadRao inefficient, or just a lot of duplicate code?  It can be made into a helper method.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Also note that you can chain your `Where` clauses. They won't be evaluated until you iterate the final collection anyway. So you can do `initialQuery = initialQuery.Where(smodel.StatusID...)` and then later (in another `if` clause) `initialQuery = initialQuery.Where(smodel.somethingElse...)`

Comment: Let me give a try @juharr.. One moment please.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I just realized that you'll want that predicate to be an expression if you pass it to EF, so I've updated the helper method in my answer.

Comment: @juharr I hope this should be `Func<bool> condition` instead of `Func<boo> condition,` right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yeah, just a typo.  Fixed now.

Comment: No probs, but am seeing some error in `return collection.Where(predicate);` line which says **System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> does not contain definition for Where and the best overloaded method ..... has some invalid argument**.. Anything am missing?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Well since you're working with EF you might need to change all the `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable`.  Though that's not the exception I would have expected.  You do have a `using System.Linq` in the file you added the `ConditionalWhere` method right?

Comment: @juharr Yes I am.. and there is also `System.Linq.Expressions` now.. So what do you suggest?

Comment: @juharr where would you suggest adding `ConditionalWhere` logic?

Answer (score 3):

So if `smodel.StatusID` is null, you want to return all the records?

```
var query=db.tblProperties.Where(p => smodel.StatusID == null || smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
                          .Select(x=>x).ToList();
```

So if you look at the `Where` clause now, if `smodel.StatusID == null` then *every* item will pass the `Where` clause. Note that the `.Contains` won't be called because of short cutting (if the first term of an OR is true, there's no point evaluating the second, so it won't).

You might also consider doing something like this:

```
.Where(p => smodel.StatusID == null || 
            !smodel.StatusID.Any() || 
            smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
```

That way you are checking both that `StatusID` is not null and that the collection `StatusID` isn't empty.

If you can make `StatusID` default to an empty collection instead of null (for example, set it in the constructor of whatever class `smodel` is), then you can do this:

```
.Where(p => !smodel.StatusID.Any() || 
        smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
```

Since you won't need the `null` check anymore and `Any` should be translatable into LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Why would you do `.Select(x=>x)` ? Afaik it's just to fetch the records as enumerable, but you already do `ToList()` so kind of pointless

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: Because that's what the OP had. The issue is with the `Where` clause. But yes, the `Select` as they had it does nothing useful.

Comment: Am getting this exception now - `Cannot compare elements of type 'System.String[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: What is the type of `smodel.StatusID`? What is the type of `p.PropertyLocation`?

Comment: @MattBurland Type of `smodel.StatusID` is `string[]` and `p.propertyLocation` is just a `string`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Ah, yeah. Translating to SQL it doesn't have a way to translate the `smodel.StatusID == null` part. You can either do what juharr suggested, or you could drop the `null` check and make `StatusID` default to an empty list and check for an empty list instead.

Answer (score 3):

Posted answers are correct and gave you the solution you need, I will go with checking for null, if you need this behavior in couple of places. If this request is repetitive in many places, i will go with the below solution.

There is another, more cleaner way if you're doing a lot of this checking, will be to add  [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) to do it for you.

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic,
>   there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method
>   and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

**Code:**

```
public static class CollectionExtension
{
    public static bool CheckContainsIfHasValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
    {
        return source == null || source.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var query = db.tblProperties
            .Where(p => smodel.StatusID.CheckContainsIfHasValue(p.PropertyLocation))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: You certainly *could* do that if you use it in lots of places, but it might be overkill if you only have a couple of places you need it. Also, I'm not sure about the name `CheckContainsIfHasValue`, but can't think of a better one.

Comment: @MattBurland, You right Matt, I wonder if to write it down or to settle with the first line, but i'll add it now. And picking the name gave me the same frustration. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a null check in your where clause:

```
 var query=db.tblProperties.Where(p => smodel.StatusID == null || smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
                           .Select(x=>x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# uses [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of Boolean expressions. This means that C# stops evaluating an expression as soon as its result can be determined.

For instance in `a && b`, the result is known to be `false` if `a` is `false`, so `b` will not be evaluated. In `a || b` the result is known to be `true` if `a` is `true`, so `b` will not be evaluated.

You can use this to protect you from an exception by adding a null-test:

```
var query = db.tblProperties
    .Where(p => smodel.StatusID == null || 
                smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
    .ToList();
```

You can also drop the `.Select(x=>x)` part as it is doing nothing.

---

If you are using LINQ to EF then the text above does not apply. You cannot perform a null check on a collection, as this cannot translate to SQL. Instead make the check before:

```
bool ignore = smodel.StatusID == null || !smodel.StatusID.Any();
var query = db.tblProperties
    .Where(p => ignore || 
                smodel.StatusID.Contains(p.PropertyLocation))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: True, but this looks like EF and so the logic will actually be translated to SQL and run in a DB.

Comment: Exception when using above query - **Cannot compare elements of type 'System.String[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao This is a reason to do the `null` check outside of the query as EF doesn't know how to translate it to SQL.